# How would I investigate the convergence of the following series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{2}{20}+\frac{3}{38}-\frac{4}{56}+\frac{5}{74}$$

Denominators increase by 18. That's most far I've gotten. Couldn't apply the diritchlet test either - any hints?

Comment: So, you're looking at $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n+1}{18n+2}$?  Shouldn't the $n$-th term not converge to zero?

Comment: As far as it seems $a_n \not\to 0$, thus the sum diverges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{n+1}{18n+2}=\frac{1}{18}\ne 0$$ , the alternating sum is not converging. I am not sure whether it diverges to $\infty$ or whether it oscillates.

Comment: The sum of each pair leaves a remainder that is $O(1/n)$ so the partial sum to $N$ diverges at $O(\log(N))$.

Comment: Since $(n+1)/(18n+2)>1/36$ for all but finitely many $n$, the sum diverges to $\infty$.If the terms converge to a positive limit $L$ then only finitely many of the terms are less than $L/2$...... In general, the sum of an infinite sequence of non-negative terms either converges or goes to $\infty.$